# How to change the default Outlook Startup folder using C#?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to change the default Outlook Startup folder using C#.

Thank you

Comment: There is a lack of details. Wich Outlook version? When and from who is executed the C# pogram?

Comment: outlook version - 2013 and 2016, 
from who is executed - when outlook startup complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the folder being displayed in Outlook at any moment using the following (null checking omitted):

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = AnyOtherMAPIFolder;
```